Enabling Windows Policy Breaks Windows Hello PIN
In the Windows Local Security Policy (secpol.msc) I enabled the following policy:
Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL + ALT + DEL --> DISABLED

So my computer requires the users to hit Ctrl + Alt + Del before they can log in. Setting the policy has however messed up the Windows Hello PIN.
The login screen will display the following messages after entering the wrong PIN:

“Your credentials could not be verified.”




“Something went wrong and your PIN isn't available (status: 0xc000006d, substatus: 0xc0000072). Click to set up your PIN again.”


Clicking on the option "Set up my PIN" will result in a Windows account login…
Microsoft account login (on login screen)

If I close the sign in windows for the Microsoft account login page, then the system will revert back to the Windows Hello PIN entry.
Is there a way to fix this issue?

Checking NTSTATUS reveals that 0xc0000072 means STATUS_ACCOUNT_DISABLED. I would first check if login was accidentally disabled while adjusting policy.

No the account is not disabled.
